# How to recover merge commit after checkout?

Tags: git, merge, git-checkout

I started on `master` and sought to merge a series of commits from `branch`: `git merge branch`. I resolved half a dozen conflicts between that branch and master. Then I was ready to commit, but decided for sanity I wanted to commit the merge commit to a new branch, `experimental`, so I ran `git checkout -b experimental`, then committed the resolved commits. When I did, to my dismay, I found that the new commit on `experimental` had only one parent (master), effectively a squash commit.

Is there a way to re-do the merge without having to re-do the merge conflicts? That is, I'd like to create a commit in new branch whose parents are `master` and `branch` and whose changes resolve to `experimental`. Is it possible?

Also, how could I have avoided losing the parents in my original situation, where I decided I wanted to commit the merge to a different branch?

Comment: Is the name `branch` here a simple placeholder to avoid using the real branch name which is irrelevant to the problem? I ask because I just tried it out of curiosity on a spare repo and yes you actually *can* name a branch `branch`, even if it's arguably a (possibly very) bad idea. Interesting question, anyway, sorry for the off-topic.

Comment: Yes, good point. I tried to use a generic but descriptive name to exemplify the problem, but I see now that using `branch` as the branch name could be confusing. I'll avoid that in the future. I won't edit this question as the answers already also use the name `branch`.

Answer (score 3):

I figured it out.

I first create a new merge commit that has the ancestry I'm seeking. I use `--strategy ours` to save time resolving merges:

```
git checkout -b remerge master
git merge branch -s ours
```

I then checkout the experimental branch and use `reset --soft`:

```
git checkout experimental
git reset --soft remerge
git commit -a --amend
```

And then cleanup:

```
git branch -D remerge
```

To avoid this in the first place, the only thing I can think of is I should have committed the merge in the original branch (master), then created a branch, then reset master.

Answer (score 2):

If you have all the changes you want in `experimental`, you can make a new commit using [git commit-tree](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit-tree):

- use `git cat-file commit experimental` to get tree hash (i.e. contents you want in the merge commit)
- make a merge commit manually: `git commit-tree -p master -p branch ${tree_hash} -m 'commit msg'`

This will print a hash of a new commit, which you can then merge into master, and fix commit message using `git commit --amend`.